# Netbeans 7.0.1 for java GUI application

Tags: java, netbeans

Can anybody help me with the following error which I am facing while creating a GUI application connecting with MySQL database.

`swing-app-framework` library could not be found
`beans-binding librar`y could not be found
`toplink` library could not be found

I am beginner in `Netbeans 7.0.1`.
What kind of error is this? If I guess this error occurs due to some missing libraries/packages. Where will I get the missing libraries/packages?

Comment: Do **not** use the Swing Application Framework! Support in NetBeans has been removed because the JSR itself is obsolete.

Comment: The horse is right, do not use Swing app framework, you won't be able to edit your forms with the very following release of netbeans (7.1) !

Answer (score 1):

Try going in Tools -> Library and seeing if Beans Bindings, Swing Application Framework and TopLink are referenced with the correct classpath

Comment: @to Helpers. So how can i create gui application using NetBean 7.0.1 without using swing .. eagerly waiting for all urs reply

Answer (score 0):

Try going in Tools -> Library and seeing if Beans Bindings, Swing Application Framework and TopLink are referenced with the correct classpath and run this application